# CSS cascade priority doesn't show right with Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have this problem, I got a project on html and css and if I open the index.html it works just find but when I put it in ruby on rails seems like the css doesn't work as supposed to do it.

This is a part of the css, just to be more clear what I want to explain.

```
#hero {
background: #0619c3 url("bg_hero.jpg");
background-size: cover; }
#hero .container {
  background: url("estudiante.png") no-repeat bottom right;
  background-size: contain; }
#hero .container .row {
  width: 44%;
  padding: 20% 2%; }
  #hero .container .row h1 {
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-bottom: 10px; }
    #hero .container .row h1 span {
      color: #fd78ed; }
  #hero .container .row p {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px; }
  #hero.orientador {
     background: #1785fb url("bg-orientadores.jpg") repeat-y;
     background-size: 36%; }
  #hero.orientador .row {
     background: url("estudiantes.png") no-repeat left 114%;
     background-size: 36%; }
  #hero.padre {
     background: #1785fb url("bg-padres.jpg") repeat-y;
     background-size: 36%; }
  #hero.padre .row {
     background: url("oriem-logo.svg") no-repeat left 58%;
     background-size: 34%; }
```

The thing it's the there is a CSS cascade priority but when I put in Ruby on Rails it doesn't priorities the containers and show all.

When I open the inspect with just the html and css it show me something like this

[Inspect with html and css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxNhr.jpg)

And this is what the inspect show me when I add the css in Ruby on Rails

[Inspect when I run it with Ruby on Rails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTCdp.png)

I also have tried with a precompiled assets, with different web browser.

Comment: By looking at the screenshot it looks like the `#page #hero .container` is defined later on in the CSS code (line 218). Are you sure you have it in the CSS for Rails app?

Comment: Yes! I just check it again. The CSS on Rails app it's basically the same and even if I look the in the source at the web browser it still there but it doesn't show as it suppose to be.

Comment: So the CSS is fine. Can you please make sure that `.container` is inside both `#hero` and `#page` elements (by checking page source code)?

Comment: Solved it! Turns out that #page was in the body tag and when I put in on Rails I just delete it so it will never found it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by missing id (`#page`) for the body.